# Call no-virtual subclass method from a pointer base abstract class

Tags: c++

I need to use a pointer of class `A`. But how can I call the class `B` method in this way?
The method is not `virtual`, it owns at class `B`.

```
class A
{
private:
    string x;
public:
    virtual void J() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    int y;
public:
    virtual void J(){
        cout << "J()";
    }
    void K(){
        cout << "K()";
    }
};

int main(){
    B b;
    A* a = &b;
    K(); //How can I call method K() with pointer a?
}
```

Comment: You cannot, you must convert the pointer to a pointer to B (using `static_cast`). But the question is suspect: why do you need that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dynamic_cast`, you may do

```
B b;
A* a = &b;
if (auto* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(a)) {
     bp->K();
}
```

but you should probably rethink your design.